# Powershell script that looks for processes and returns process, computername and username

Tags: powershell

I'd like to search through ten terminal servers after users that are running a specific program. I want the output to include process, computername and user.

This command basically does what I want:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content .\test-servers.txt) -ScriptBlock { get-wmiobject win32_process|where{$_.name -eq "iexplore.exe" }|select name, __SERVER,@{n="owner";e={$_.getowner().user}}} | Format-Table name, PSComputerName, owner -AutoSize

name         PSComputerName owner 
----         -------------- ----- 
iexplore.exe mrdsh-test     dojo03
iexplore.exe mrdsh-test     dojo03
iexplore.exe mrdsh-test     baob12
iexplore.exe mrdsh-test     baob12
```

But when I try to create a script which takes the process as a parameter I can't get it to work.

```
CmdletBinding()]
Param (
[parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$process
)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content .\test-servers.txt) -ScriptBlock { get-wmiobject win32_process | where{param($process)$_.name  -eq $process } | select name, __SERVER,@{n="owner";e={$_.getowner().user}}} | Format-Table name, PSComputerName, owner -AutoSize
```

I haven't managed to send the $process parameter to the server that's invoking the command. How to I do that? Or is there an easier way to look for processes and return process, computername and username?

Comment: 'I can't get it to work'... have you some error?

Answer (score 1):

You have param($process) in your where scriptblock, and you don't set it, so it will be empty.

**Edit:**

As requested, taking param out the following works on my machine:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
[parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$process
)

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { get-wmiobject win32_process | where{ $_.name  -eq $process } | select name, __SERVER,@{n="owner";e={$_.getowner().user}}} | Format-Table name, PSComputerName, owner -AutoSize
```

It also works in Powershell version 1:

```
powershell -version 1.0 -noprofile -Command ".\test.ps1 -process 'chrome.exe'"
```

works just fine.

Comment: I thought I'm setting it by adding it as a parameter when I run the script "LookForProcess.ps1 iexplore.exe"

Comment: Have you tried it without the param($process) in the where block? Still have issues? The parameter of the script is a different one from the one in your where block.

Comment: There's no difference in the results if I remove param($process) in the where block.

Ok, it's my first attempt of writing a powershell script. Learning by doing :)

Comment: Not sure I can help then, I tested it locally and it works just fine for me.

Comment: Oh, that's strange. Could you paste your working script? Perhaps I've made some small mistake that you haven't done.